# Different Thread at same time in C# MVC3 Web Application

Tags: c#, multithreading, asp.net-mvc-3, backgroundworker, background-process

I've never really used threading before in C# where I need to have six threads which need to be execute at the same time. Here is the sample steps

1-User will invoke a print request

2- Need to create 5 thread in the background. This will invoke at the same time and These five thread will create five PDF document.

3- Merge five documents and send response back to the user.

Is it possible to handle this by using multi threading in C#. If possible how can i hold initial request.

Additional. Is t possible to make number of thread in a dynamic way.(I mean some time 5 thread sometime 6...)

Please help me to make a good decision

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Looking for some thing like this

```
var task1 = Task.Run(() => Funct1());    
 var task2 = Task.Run(() =>  Funct2());
 var task3 = Task.Run(() => Funct3());    
 var task4 = Task.Run(() =>  Funct4());
 var task5 = Task.Run(() => Funct5());          

    int totalSlept = task1.Result + task2.Result+task3.Result + task4.Result+task5.Result
```

Comment: but i need to wait my initial request until all the five task are completed.

Comment: i think you can use Task.WhenAll(task1, task2, task3,task4);